# Python module pkg_resources.require()

Tags: python, module, require, pythonpath

I have a problem loading the correct version of a python module. I have no admin rights, so the stuff installed under `$PYTHONHOME` and `$PYTHONPATH` are read only. Unfortunately the module(s) that reside there are the wrong version. I have the correct version in `/some/other/directory`
How do I load the correct version instead of the one installed under `$PYTHONHOME`? I tried :

```
import sys
import pkg_resources
sys.path.insert(0, '/some/other/directory/pysam')
pkg_resources.require("pysam=0.9.1.4")
import pysam
version = pkg_resources.get_distribution("pysam").version
print('version= ', version)
```

I was hoping to get version 0.9.1.4 but I don't. I still get the one installed under `$PYTHONPATH`. Prior to running the script I also tried:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/some/other/directory:$PYTHONPATH
```

still no cigar. 
Any ideas?

Comment: From what I understand this is not the source of your issue, but shouldn't `pysam=0.9.1.4` use double equals, like `pysam==0.9.1.4`?